# Typescript and wrong type inside of click handler

Tags: typescript, knockout-3.0

My TypeScript

```
export class CustomerUIModel implements CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomerUI {

    public customers: KnockoutObservableArray<CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomer>;
    service: CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomerService;



    constructor(svc: CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomerService, data: CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomer[]) {
        this.service = svc;
        this.customers = ko.observableArray(data);
    }

    public AddCustomer(elem: CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomer): void {
        this.service.Insert(elem)
            .then(cRes => {
                this.customers.push(elem);
            })
            .catch(r => {
                alert(r.message);
            });
    }
}}
```

My HTML:

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="5" data-bind="value: CustomerID" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: CompanyName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ContactName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Country" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="form-control" value="Insert" data-bind='click: $root.AddCustomer' />
                <input type="button" class="form-control" value="Delete" data-bind='click: $root.DeleteCustomer' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

When I click on "Insert" I get into AddCustomer() but *this.service* is NULL as well as *customers*. Moreover,"this" has a CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomer, not a CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomerService as I expect. How can I have this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Knockout is not calling the `AddCustomer` method with the `this` context you want.  See [this thread](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/244).  You can force the `this` context to be your `CustomerUIModel` object by binding the method like this:

```
public AddCustomer = (elem: CustomerIntrerfaces.ICustomer): void => {
    this.service.Insert(elem)
        .then(cRes => {
            this.customers.push(elem);
        })
        .catch(r => {
            alert(r.message);
        });
}
```

See [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) for more information about the general problem.

Comment: I don't understand your objection to `=>` notation, but there are some other options in the threads I linked.